# I don't understand why my indentation is wrong, and when I input an answer it doesn't output anything, other than an error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running this using PyScripter w/ Python 2.7.6. I don't understand why my code is wrong. Could someone give me an explanation?

```
def mainMenu():
answer = input("""Main Menu:
Pythagoras
Repeat Program
Quit""")
if answer == "Pythagoras":
    pythagoras()
elif answer == "Repeat Program":
    mainMenu()
elif answer == "Quit":
    print("Program ended")
else:
    mainMenu()

def pythagoras():
if answer == "Pythagoras":
    aNotSquared = input("Input the value of A")
bNotSquared = input("Input the value of B")

aSquared = aNotSquared ** 2
bSquared = bNotSquared ** 2

valueC = aSquared + bSquared

print(valueC)


mainMenu()
```

Comment: Do you understand that you need an indentation after `def` ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry it didn't show up on here, I'm new to this site.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] including your *actual* indentation; it matters in Python. Read the editing help.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for being dumb.

Comment: @sambarringer, you're not being dumb. You're new. There's a difference. Please [edit] your question, re-paste your code, then select it and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button to indent the whole thing. That should preserve your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if indentation errors occured when pasting over but outside that are a couple things to fix as well

- Already test `if answer == 'Pythagoras'` before entering the `pythagoras()` function, doesn't work nor make sense to check `answer` inside the function
- Cannot perform math on `strings` need to convert your input to `int`
- General formatting for clarity, when taking inputs and printing result
- PEP-8 `snake_case` not `CamelCase`

Slightly Improved Version:

```
from math import sqrt

def main_menu():
    answer = input("""Main Menu:
    Pythagoras
    Repeat Program
    Quit\nChoose option from above: """)
    if answer == "Pythagoras":
        pythagoras()
    elif answer == "Repeat Program":
        main_menu()
    elif answer == "Quit":
        print("Program ended")
    else:
        main_menu()

def pythagoras():
    a_not_sqr = int(input("Input the value of A: "))
    b_not_sqr = int(input("Input the value of B: "))

    a_sqr = a_not_sqr ** 2
    b_sqr = b_not_sqr ** 2

    c_sqr = a_sqr + b_sqr
    c_not_sqr = sqrt(c_sqr)

    print(f'C Squared  = {c_sqr}')
    print(f'C = {round(c_not_sqr, 2)}')

main_menu()
```

> ```
> Main Menu:
>     Pythagoras
>     Repeat Program
>     Quit
> Choose option from above: Pythagoras
> Input the value of A: 10
> Input the value of B: 10
> C Squared  = 200
> C = 14.14
> ```